# C# Split container doesn't resize with the Form window

Tags: c#, winforms

Created a hello world C# api and when I maximize the form windows, the split container doesn't resize with the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the visual studio form properties editor you can set the split container control property Dock to DockStyle.Fill in the properties for the control.  You can also do this in the form source code.

```
mysplitContainer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

When you do this, any control whose dock is set to Fill will resize to fill the entire space of its parent control, so if you have a case where you have a form, with a single SplitContainer in it, the split container will occupy the full space of the form and it will adjust automatically on any form resize (including Maximize)

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for response and for the link, I'll look more onto that site before asking from now on.